# Licensing system for a C# application with a PHP backend

Tags: c#, php

I have a C# application and I want to make a licensing system for it by checking the response from a remote PHP script.

My C# part:

```
/* License check */
            try
            {
                string URI = "https://example.com/licensing.php";
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                    System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection postData =
                        new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection()
                   {
                          { "secret", "Secret123" },  
                          { "license", "license123" }
                   };
                    string pagesource = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.UploadValues(URI, postData));
                    LicenseCheck licensecheck = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LicenseCheck>(pagesource);

                    if (licensecheck.secret == "Secret123")
                    {
                        if (licensecheck.valid != true)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("[ERROR] Invalid license.");
                            Console.ReadKey();
                            Environment.Exit(0);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("[ERROR] Invalid license.");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                    }
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[ERROR] Invalid license.");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
```

My PHP part:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

if( !isset($_POST['secret']) || empty($_POST['secret']) || $_POST['secret'] !== "Secret123" ) {
    die();
}

if( !isset($_POST['license']) || empty($_POST['license']) ) {
    die();
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die();
} 

$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM licenses WHERE license='".$_POST['license']."'");

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo json_encode(array(
        'valid' => true,
        'secret' => $_POST['secret']
    ));
    die();
} else {
    echo json_encode(array(
        'valid' => false,
        'secret' => $_POST['secret']
    ));
    die();
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

So, this works by sending the license input from the C# application to the remote PHP script along with the `secret` which is `Secret123` for example.

After that, the PHP script will return JSON data like that:

`{"valid":true,"secret":"Secret123"}`

Now, my C# application will verify if the secret which was outputed in the JSON == `Secret123` - If yes then it will verify if `valid` is true.

But my program got cracked by changing the `hosts` file and spoofing my PHP script server.

How? So the cracker used a HTTP debugger like Fiddler and he knew the value of the POST field `secret` although I am using `https` which should encrypt the POST data.

**EDIT**: Also of course my C# application is highly obfuscated.

How can I fix that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Using a prepared statement may / could help, seeing you're open to an SQL injection and probably found their way through that security gap/hole.

Comment: @Mehdi - Read the question well, I say that I am already using HTTPS but the debugger got the POST data too.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - Yes I know that, but the SQL injection is not the problem.

Comment: maybe not now but later; yes. *Just saying*.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - Yes surely I will fix that once I fix the problem of getting it cracked.

Comment: All an attacker needs do is like you say set up hosts file, https won't protect your app, your app will just try https where ever the attacker wants.. heard of selfsigned?, the attacker just need to get the hardcoded licence values Secret123 etc.. then mock it against your real system, get the response, then mock it on there own response.. or just bypass the whole check logic by cracking it. Whatever you try there is a way around it so instead just licence it with a legal licence and give up on a remote check.

Comment: btw obfuscated does not look obfuscated in memory stack..

Comment: Increase complexity using hashing and encryption based on time.

Comment: @MatrixCow08 Since you use HTTPS, can't you just check the server certificate in the request/response? If it doesn't match your server then the response isn't from your server.

Answer (score 0):

As M.Hassan had said in the comments, I can encrypt the 'current time' values in the PHP script and return them in JSON or XML, then decrypt the JSON/XML output (based on the same encryption I used in the PHP script) in the C# application and check `if the decrypted JSON/XML time = the current time` then the validation is correct.